# React 17 cannot get height of node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react 16, there are 2 ways to get height of a component / node.

1. use callback ref
2. get height in componentDidMount by ref (in Class component)
3. useRef() and get height by ref.current.clientHeight (in Functional Component)

However, none of them works in react 17. Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: Have provided a complete answer and solution for your question. Try it once. And if you need any more help :) I am here to help. Don't worry

Comment: And yes don't forget to vote and accept the answer for other developers to benefit from it :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

`React-17` does have `useRef()` Hook to do this. There is a `current` property on your `useRef()` Hook. And yes, implementation has changed a bit. We use `useRef()` and assign it to a variable in our Component.

```
 const myDiv = useRef();
```

Then use `ref={myDiv}` on our JSX element to be tracked by `myDiv` variable ref. I have provided the demo code. Click on the div and you get back the details in

```
myDiv.current
```

**Demo Code:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const myStyle = {
  height: "100px",
  border: "1px solid orange"
};
export default function App() {
  const myDiv = useRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
     console.log(myDiv.current.clientHeight);// 100
     console.log(myDiv.current.style.height);// 100px
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={myDiv} style={myStyle} onClick={handleClick}>
        My demo div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CODESANDBOX WORKING CODE:** https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-ldu3t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My dear Friend. I use it often. Don't worry. I will provide a demo code in my answer  for you .:)